# Unable to get call details using MS graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, call, microsoft-teams, communication, microsoft-graph-teams

I am unable to get call details or call records using graph api.It's saying forbidden in response although I am using application token.In the docs I don't see any extra permission required for this.

Below are the details:

```
Method : GET
API CALL : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/ce4e4e99-be1b-4c6e-8c43-22308f968d3e

Response : 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "4e603f5c-3ac8-466c-acde-24e40f1d6309",
            "date": "2021-06-17T13:51:08",
            "client-request-id": "4e603f5c-3ac8-466c-acde-24e40f1d6309"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the basic requirement for this do I need to set some permission while call in order to get the call record as I am able to call user through graph API.Call.Records.All permission has been set for record and get data.
Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this issue, Let us investigate at our end.

Comment: Could you please check the permission in the scope by using JWT token and check.

Comment: Yes  I have checked all the permission and they are allowed and admin consent has been granted too.

Comment: Please check the permissions in the token you have generated using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)?

Comment: Basically I am getting call details now. The main issue is of nothing but untill the call is running I will not get any record. Once the call is finished after that I will get response after 10-15minutes. Can you please tell me which api to call to get instant ongoing call details. Thanks

Comment: @Sanjeev_gupta2812- could you please post the answer on how did you resolve your issue? This will help other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API works as it is with the same request but the only issue is that it will return response after certain cases.
The cases are :

```
1.The call must has ended.

2.Record has been created in the log of Microsoft which usually takes time.
3.Try running the same API with the same configuration but after around 10-15 minutes you will surely get the response.
```

Follow the document from MS docs for /communincation/calls. The only etxra thing which is not mentioned is that it return after 15min(approx.) call has ended.

This will help others not to get panic as I was.

Thanks